# google code + temp server?

Tags: python, django

We are starting a new project to develop a website using django. We have created a project on google code. We would like to be able to occasionally show the progress of the site to some people, without having to purchase a real server.

We are all modifying the project through eclipse and SVN. What's the best way to create a runserver type thing but allow othes to access over the internet temporarily?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to run Django development server to bind on multiple interfaces:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Or specify a IP of the interface to bind to, for example this would only listen on the interface who's IP is 192.168.1.100:

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.100:8000
```

But Django development server is single threaded and thus will not work good with concurrent requests.

I would advise setting up a development preview on shared hosting or something, or even locally, with a proper web server (such as Apache or ngnix).

If you do it locally just portforward your traffic from router to your local installation, if you don't have static IP you can use a service such as [DynDns](http://www.dyndns.com/) or [No-ip](http://www.no-ip.com/).

This subject has been covered several times on Stackoverflow, feel free to search for other ideas.