# Is Django's HTTP server rejecting remote requests by default?

Tags: django, httpserver

I've got django running on a dev. box that I'd like to be able to make requests to from another dev. box on my LAN. I'm getting no response at all though, even though I can ping just fine, no firewalls are operating, etc.

Is there a setting in Django somewhere that prevents it from responding to remote requests by default?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you binding the Django server to 127.0.0.1 perchance? Or are you binding to the IP addres assigned to an interface that is reachable by the other computer?

---

To bind the server to another address look at using `python manage.py runserver <ip address>:<port>` as answered in this StackOverflow question: [google code + temp server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698964/google-code-temp-server/3699019#3699019)

Also see the [manage.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port) documentation from Django.

Do note that there is going to be a performance impact, the dev server is not meant for concurrent access and will perform poorly if multiple people are browsing at the same time..

Comment: Based on this line in the initial output when I run the server, I'm probably binding to 127.0.0.1:

Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8079/

Comment: I've modified my answer to include the command to bind to a different ip/port.